# Expectation of a posterior distribution

Tags: probability, bayesian, variance

I'm trying to solve the following problem (under which is my attempt at it)

[image]

I'm confused on how to solve for the expectation here in a non-conditional manner (summing over all values of n) without doing it manually. Any help would be great! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the same symbol to refer both to a random variable and to the argument to its probability mass function is atrocious notation. Also, the notation should be established before the list of multiple-choice answers appears, i.e. it should say something like "Let $X$ be the number of heads that appear, and let $N$ be the number of rolls before a $6$ appears."

Now we can say things like $\operatorname E(X\mid N=6) = \frac 1 2 \cdot 12 = 6.$

And $\operatorname E(X\mid N) = N.$

And finally, $ \displaystyle \operatorname E(X) = \operatorname E( \operatorname E(X\mid N)) = \operatorname E(N) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n\Pr(N=n).$

Notice the difference between capital $N,$ the random variable, and lower-case $n,$ the thing that runs through the list of possible values of (capital) $N.$ Without that distinction, one cannot even understand something like $\Pr(N=n).$

Comment: woops sorry about the notation. You're right, it is confusing and I shouldn't have half-assed it. And ooh, you're right. That's a smart use of the Law of Iterated Expectations. Thanks!

Comment: @Anthony : I'm glad it helped. I prefer the name "law of total expectation." And "law of total variance" for the proposition that $\operatorname{var}(A) = \operatorname{var}(\operatorname E(A\mid B)) + \operatorname E(\operatorname{var}(A\mid B)). \qquad$

Comment: Just one more follow-up: shouldn't E(N) be summation of n*Pr(N=n)? Thanks! And it seems like that series isn't geometric or anything, so would I just have to manually calculate what it approaches?

Comment: @Anthony : Typo. Fixed. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

There is a probability of $\frac16$ that the game ends right away with a $6$ and a probability of $\frac56$ that you flip two fair coins and are then back in the initial situation. The expected number of heads from two fair coins is $1$. Thus, the expected number of heads $E$ in the initial situation satisfies

$$
E = \frac16\cdot0+\frac56(1+E)\;,
$$

with solution $E=5$.

Comment: Your logic makes sense to me until you write the equation out. Sorry for this maybe being a dumb question, but could you expand as to how you came up with the equation? And does that equation also work for all cases of n (e.g 1 roll, 2 rolls, 3 rolls, etc)? Thanks!

Comment: @Anthony: Yes, it works for all cases. The equation makes use of the [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity). With probability $\frac16$, you get $0$ heads; that's the first term. With probability $\frac56$, you get two fair coins (from which we expect $1$ heads), plus whatever you get from continuing the game. The point is that continuing the game here is equivalent to starting the game over, because the rules from this point on are exactly the rules starting from the initial situation. So we can expect another $E$ heads from the rest of the game.